# Скрыть показать элемент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть код, правда он показывает при клике на 1 кнопку сразу все блоки, потому как на странице один и тот же шаблон используется.

Код:

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-dates-event').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        if (!$( event.target ).is('.event_list_more')) {
            $(".event_list_more").toggle('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

Код html:

```
<div class="event_list">
<div class="event__list_block">
    <p class="dates-event">
        <span>Апрель 30 - Мая 3, 2020</span>
        <a class="toggle-dates-event">Другие даты</a>
    </p>
</div>
<div class="event_list_more">
    <p class="text-normal">Другие даты:</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(function(){
    $('.toggle-dates-event').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).closest(".event_list").find(".event_list_more").toggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: Блок, который нужно открывать, находится не внутри с кнопкой, а за пределами блока.

Comment: @Ivan Это я должен был сам догадаться?

Comment: извините, забыл сразу указать

Comment: @Ivan Приведите типичный кусок html-а.

Comment: привел, в задании выше

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: Я так и не понял, ему надо было включать html в вопрос или нет?)